# Join clause from one table to another to where one table has its foreign key mixed

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I wish to join two tables (reservation and facility_items). The reservation.facility_item_id is composed of multiple facility_item_id in a single row. And now I am having trouble joining them because I can't connect the `reservation.facility_item_id` to `facility_items.facility_item_id`

Here is the structure of my tables:

> reservation

[image: a busy cat]

> facility_item

[image: facility_item]

> reservation content

[image: reservation content]

> facility_item content

[image: facility_item content]

```
`SELECT * FROM reservations r 
JOIN facility_items f on r.facility_item_id IN 
(
  SELECT facility_item_id 
  FROM facility_items
)`
```

lmao. I do not even know what I am doing but thats my start.

Expected result should show 3 facility_item_id but instead, I got this:

[image: actual result]

Comment: When possible, post sample table structures and data vs pictures that might be blocked / filtered..  Put what CAN be into the original post please.

Comment: I do not understand sir @DRapp. What do you mean by blocked/filtered pictures ?

Comment: Corporate firewalls may and do block content from not-so-trusted/common sites.  So I can't see your images to understand what the underlying source is to try and answer.  Rarely should pictures be inserted.

Comment: How your multiple facility_item_id is storing multiple ids in one row? comma separated or what? post a sample data of your tables to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I really didn't check the content on the tables, it is indeed more complicated than a simple join. I guess you are complicating things because this a  1xN relation and you are storing it on the wrong side (the 1 side instead of the N side).

You should have a field in your facility table which shoud store the ID of the reservation. Then a simple join will suffice:

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservations r JOIN facility f  
  ON r.reservation_id = f.reservation_id
```

**First attempt, Won't work**

It seems that a simple join should suffice. Can you try this one?

```
SELECT * 
FROM reservations r JOIN facility_items f 
  ON r.facility_item_id = f.facility_item_id
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you sir, indeed, a simple join was correct.